# Proving $\lim_\limits{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)}{\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I know that $$\lim_\limits{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\lim_\limits{x \to 0} f(x)}{\lim\limits_{x \to 0} g(x)}$$ but only if $\lim_\limits{x \to 0} g(x) \neq 0$, $\lim_\limits{x \to 0} f(x) = A \in \mathbb{R},$ $\lim_\limits{x \to 0} g(x) = B \in \mathbb{R}$.

And my question is, can we omit the condition $\lim_\limits{x \to 0} g(x) \neq 0$? I mean, is it true that

> If $\lim_\limits{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = L \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\lim_\limits{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$.

because otherwise, if $\lim_\limits{x \to 0} f(x) = A \leq \infty, A \neq 0 $ then $\lim_\limits{x \to 0} \dfrac{f(x)}{x} = A \times \lim_\limits{x \to 0} \dfrac{1}{x} = A \times \infty$ cannot be equal to real number.

Comment: The marked claim is true indeed. Your arguments are not completely mathematical though.

Comment: @Yanko Why? Because I multiply by infinity?

Comment: As you mentioned at the beginning,you can only use the arithmetic properties of the $\lim$ (say $\lim(f\cdot g)  = \lim f \cdot \lim g$) only if both $\lim f$ and $\lim g$ exist.

Comment: Also another problem is that you're assuming that $f(x)$ convergence to something (while not converging to zero doesn't mean it is convergence to something else).

Comment: @Yanko yes, I agree. It's a very useful remark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formal proof for the marked claim:

You're given that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for every $x\in (-\delta,\delta), x\not = 0$ we have $$|\frac{f(x)}{x}-L|<\varepsilon$$

Fix $\varepsilon=1$, so for a fixed $\delta$ we have that $L-1<\frac{f(x)}{x}<L+1$ for all $x\in (-\delta,\delta),x\not= 0$.

In particular it follows that $|f(x)|<\max(|x|(L+1),|x|(L-1))$ for all $x\not=0$ in an interval around zero. Thus, $|f(x)|$ convergence to zero as $x$ goes to zero.

Now it is not quit trivial (not that hard as well) to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}|f(x)|=0$ implies that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)=0$ which is what you wanted to prove.

Edit: It turns out to be even simpler than that (See the comment of Theo Bendit) using the algebra of limits theorems since $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{x} = L$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x = 0$ we have that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{x} \cdot \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x = L\cdot 0 = 0$

Comment: Using the algebra of limits theorem, $$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} x = L \cdot 0 = 0.$$

Comment: @TheoBendit That's actually very nice!